# How to compile kernel with bigge page size

Tags: linux-kernel

I tried to mount a parition with block size larger than 4kb. 
the operation failed with the following error:

```
Function not implemented
```

(I tried enabling Huge Pages, got the same error).

After some research I found that this is probably due to the blocksize being larger than the os page size.

As I understand the page size is determined at compile time,
so I'd like to try compile a kernel with different page size.

Comment: Cross-dup (similar question on other SE site): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80725/change-the-size-of-my-memory-pages.

Comment: Already tried that, still couldn't mount the partition

Answer (score 0):

You can use these kernel configurations from `make menuconfig` and change the page size.

```
    CONFIG_<ARCH>_4K_PAGES
    CONFIG_<ARCH>_16K_PAGES
    CONFIG_<ARCH>_64K_PAGES
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and see if it works. Is it possible to make page size larger than 64kb?

Comment: Increasing page size is depends upon the processor capability. I believe 64K is a best size of page.
Also notice that when page size is increasing, smaller memory requirements also will be assigned 64K
(eg, If some process requires only 4K size page, but it will be assigned 64K and remaining 60K is unused.)

Comment: couldn't find these items in menuconfig.  the only mention of page size  I found was in ./include/asm-parisc/mman.h:   MADV_4K_PAGES   12                               and different numbers defined for 64k and 256k, but I'm not sure which files use these definitions